# How to call action of JSP page before user request for new page in struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts

I have a menubar page in JSP and within I'm loading different JSP pages. My one JSP page contains portlets developed in **Dojo** with drag and drop functionality. When any user requests for new page by clicking on menubar or by closing the application, I want to call the action class associated with this JSP page to save portlets position within database.

I tried to implement `window.onunload` event, but it was called for the parent container not for the page unloaded within it.

Could anyone which javascript event or struts 2 tag I require to use to accomplish this requirement?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "requests for new page by clicking on menubar or by closing the application"?

Comment: I meant on the menu item of the menu bar at the top of the application window on a jsp page

Comment: Errr... What application? Show some code/image/example.

Comment: I want drag and drop position of the portlets shown in above images to be saved first in server before user requests for new menu bar item.

Comment: So attach your saving action to drop event.

Comment: <s:action name="actionName" executeResult="true"/> use this tag to execute action in jsp.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV, rendering that way is pretty complicated. It would be easiest if he simply allowed for the editing of a block of html which included magic divs. Then using asynchronous requests the portlets could be inserted. Drag and drop will impose layout constraints which would be complicated to overcome. The page just load the block of user defined html and then, javascript kicks in and inserts content from the server into the target divs. This keeps most in line with the action paradigm.

Comment: Once this basic method works, if drag and drop is desired how to best handle layout issues could then be addressed.